# how do included dompfg in my controller action.. right now it show blank page

Tags: php, dompdf

i am using dompdf to convert html content to pdf.. this is my basic code

```
$path_pdf = BASE_PATH.'/public/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'; 
require_once($path_pdf); 
$html = '<p>Hello PHP</p>';         
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

but  at second line where i have included dompdf
... after doing it all when i run this page it shows me blank screen..and after doing some debugging i found dompdf_config.inc.php is not including...
i have checked my files path, it is correct.
Any idea..
Thank in advance.

Comment: Where does BASE_PATH come from? Are you using a framework? What happens if you specify the path either relative to your PHP script or from the root of the file system?

Comment: hi brian..
thanks for reply
i have add defined BASE_PATH in my public/index.php
And i am using Zend Framework. and there is no matter about relative path and root... actually i have defines like:
localhost/myporject/public .... and i have also checked for path it is right...

Comment: So what is the value of `$path_pdf`? Does it actually point to dompdf_config.inc.php. Also, which version of dompdf are you using. 0.5.1 did not have a very robust autoloader so you should be using 0.6.0, especially if dompdf is integrated into a framework.

Comment: thanks Brian... i have solve that...actually 
this font.cls.php files was missing from lib\php-font-lib\classes..
So it was creating problem.. now it is working fine... and i have also generated pdf... but getting some issue in paper size
when i give custom paper size... all things working properly but 
my html content is not showing complete in pdf... i have also converted inches to points ... but it is not working.. any help 
thanks in advance.